# RDS raising unwanted PostGIS NOTICEs

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgis

I have an Amazon RDS instance that is producing unwanted `NOTICE`s.
I have never seen this behaviour before.

```
mydb=> select current_setting('client_min_messages');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 notice
(1 row)
```

Now, if I ask for geometry column... I get the `NOTICE`s:

```
mydb=> SELECT id, ST_AsText(geom) FROM mytable limit 1;

NOTICE:  [lwgeom_ogc.c:LWGEOM_asText:833] Called.
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_get_type:50] entered
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:lwgeom_from_gserialized:1137] Got type 1 (Point), srid=4326
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:lwgeom_from_gserialized_buffer:1091] Got type 1 (Point), hasz=0 hasm=0 geodetic=0 hasbox=0
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_get_type:50] entered
NOTICE:  [lwgeom.c:lwgeom_set_srid:1455] entered with srid=4326
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkt.c:lwgeom_to_wkt_sb:590] lwgeom_to_wkt_sb: type Point, hasz 1, hasm 0
NOTICE:  [lwgeom_ogc.c:LWGEOM_asText:841] WKT size = 33, WKT length = 32
  id   |            st_astext             
-------+----------------------------------
 12445 | POINT(-119.67608831 48.15767852)
(1 row)
```

Setting `client_min_messages` up one level will suppress then, but then it obviously spoils `NOTICE`s for all.

```
mydb=> SET client_min_messages=WARNING;
SET
mydb=> SELECT id, ST_AsText(geom) FROM mytable limit 1;
  id   |            st_astext             
-------+----------------------------------
 12445 | POINT(-119.67608831 48.15767852)
(1 row)
```

What's going on here? My local and custom installed versions of Postgres never acted this way.

**Update:** This seems to be isolated to Postgres 9.4.4 - 9.4.1 does not raise these.

Comment: Are the extra NOTICEs only from PostGIS? Can you show `SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();` from your 9.4.1 instance which you say does not exhibit the symptoms, as well as from your 9.4.4 instance which does?

Comment: @JoshKupershmidt We're getting this as well on recently-launched instances, and we definitely __are__ on 9.4.1. What's interesting is that PostGIS seems to have gone back by a minor increment since we last launched an instance that didn't have this problem (2.1.5 --> 2.1.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem with our RDS instances for a stretch of a week, but AWS support patched it on Sept 16. Now all RDS instances we launch with postgres 9.4.4 have functional and normal-logging postgis 2.1.5 on them. Your instances should be working as expected now too.